# Why and when a LEFT JOIN with condition in WHERE clause is not equivalent to the same LEFT JOIN in ON?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join

I'm experiencing a very confusing situation that makes me question all my understanding of joins in SQL Server.

```
SELECT t1.f2 
FROM   t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 
ON t1.f1 = t2.f1 AND cond2 AND t2.f3 > something
```

Does not give the same results as :

```
SELECT t1.f2 
FROM   t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 
ON t1.f1 = t2.f1 AND cond2 
WHERE  t2.f3 > something
```

Can please someone help by telling if this two queries are supposed to be equivalent or not?

Thx

Comment: The `ON` reduces the set of rows that are joined, whereas the `WHERE` reduces the set of rows that are added to the result set...

Comment: They are not equivalent. Your first query filters the results in the join; the second filters *after*.

Comment: I'm not sure questions are equivalent because here, the condition is expressed upon the second table..

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The `on` clause is used when the `join` is looking for matching rows.  The `where` clause is used to filter rows after all the joining is done.

An example with Disney toons voting for president:

```
declare @candidates table (name varchar(50));
insert @candidates values 
    ('Obama'), 
    ('Romney');
declare @votes table (voter varchar(50), voted_for varchar(50));
insert @votes values 
    ('Mickey Mouse', 'Romney'),
    ('Donald Duck', 'Obama');

select  *
from    @candidates c
left join    
        @votes v
on      c.name = v.voted_for
        and v.voter = 'Donald Duck'
```

This still returns `Romney` even though `Donald` didn't vote for him.  If you move the condition from the `on` to the `where` clause:

```
select  *
from    @candidates c
left join    
        @votes v
on      c.name = v.voted_for
where   v.voter = 'Donald Duck'
```

`Romney` will no longer be in the result set.

Comment: Note that this example is using an OUTER join, which is the case in which these 2 code snippets are not functionally equivalent.

Comment: I was looking for something completely different, but somehow google lead me here and your fist two sentences saved my day! Thanks +1!

Answer (score 22):

Both are literally different.

The first query does the filtering of table `t2` before the joining of tables take place. So the results will then be join on table `t1` resulting all the records of `t1` will be shown on the list.

The second one filters from the total result after the joining the tables is done.

---

Here's an example

Table1

```
ID   Name
1    Stack
2    Over 
3    Flow
```

Table2

```
T1_ID   Score
1       10
2       20
3       30
```

---

In your first query, it looks like this,

```
SELECT  a.*, b.Score
FROM    Table1 a
        LEFT JOIN Table2 b
           ON a.ID = b.T1_ID AND
              b.Score >= 20
```

What it does is before joining the tables, the records of `table2` are filtered first by the score. So the only records that will be joined on table1 are

```
T1_ID   Score
2       20
3       30
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f4fd/2)

because the `Score` of `T1_ID` is only 10. The result of the query is

```
ID   Name    Score
1    Stack   NULL
2    Over    20
3    Flow    30
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f4fd/3)

---

While the second query is different.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.Score
FROM    Table1 a
        LEFT JOIN Table2 b
           ON a.ID = b.T1_ID
WHERE   b.Score >= 20
```

It joins the records first whether it has a matching record on the other table or not. So the result will be

```
ID   Name    Score
1    Stack   10
2    Over    20
3    Flow    30
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f4fd/5)

and the filtering takes place `b.Score >= 20`. So the final result will be

```
ID   Name    Score
2    Over    20
3    Flow    30
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f4fd/4)

Comment: Well explained!

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE Company
(
CompanyId TinyInt Identity Primary Key,
CompanyName Nvarchar(50) NULL
)
GO

INSERT Company VALUES('DELL')
INSERT Company VALUES('HP')
INSERT Company VALUES('IBM')
INSERT Company VALUES('Microsoft')
GO

CREATE TABLE Candidate
(
CandidateId tinyint identity primary key,
FullName nvarchar(50) NULL,
CompanyId tinyint REFERENCES Company(CompanyId)
)
GO

INSERT Candidate VALUES('Ron',1)
INSERT Candidate VALUES('Pete',2)
INSERT Candidate VALUES('Steve',3)
INSERT Candidate VALUES('Steve',NULL)
INSERT Candidate VALUES('Ravi',1)
INSERT Candidate VALUES('Raj',3)
INSERT Candidate VALUES('Kiran',NULL)
GO

SELECT * from Company c
SELECT * from Candidate c

-- A simple left outer Join
SELECT * FROM Company c LEFT OUTER JOIN Candidate c2
ON c.CompanyId = c2.CompanyId

--Left Outer Join ON and AND condition fetches 5 rows wtih NULL value from right side table 
SELECT * FROM Company c LEFT OUTER JOIN Candidate c2
ON c.CompanyId = c2.CompanyId
AND c.CompanyName = 'DELL' 

--Left Outer Join ON and where clause fetches only required rows
SELECT * FROM Company c LEFT OUTER JOIN Candidate c2
ON c.CompanyId = c2.CompanyId
AND c.CompanyName = 'DELL' 
WHERE c.CompanyName='IBM'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, results in `t2` is filtered as part of the join.

In the second case, there could be more rows available from `t2`.

Essentially, the set of records joined in the two queries will not be the same.

Answer (score 0):

It does make a difference because in second case you are applying the where AFTER it does the left join