# I have a users table and amount table, I would like to show all users with amount even when the amount is null or zero

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am using mysql.
When I use JOINS like this

```
SELECT u.Id,u.FirstName,u.LastName,u.Email,SUM(a.Amount) Amount FROM users u LEFT JOIN amount a  WHERE a.ExpenseDate >= '2013-05-12' GROUP BY u.Id
```

I have 23 users but it shows only 14 users data since the rest 9 did not enter amount.
I need all the 23 users against the amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the condition in the `ON` clause,

```
SELECT u.Id,u.FirstName,u.LastName,u.Email,SUM(a.Amount) Amount 
FROM   users u LEFT JOIN amount a ON i.ID = a.ID
       AND a.ExpenseDate >= '2013-05-12' 
GROUP  BY u.Id
```

in this case, the optimizer filters records from table `amount` first before it will be joined on table `user`.

Comment: Great it worked. Thank You. What is the difference actually? could you explain please

Comment: [more explanation on this link...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706112/why-and-when-a-left-join-with-condition-in-where-clause-is-not-equivalent-to-the)