# Why do these two queries return a different number of rows

Tags: t-sql

I'm using adventureworks2012:

The first query returns 43 rows and no nulls, whereas the second returns over 19 thousand and lots of nulls.

I thought an outer join returned rows from the left side of the query even if the condition is not met, and therefore the two queries should be equivalent?

--1

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, s.SalesOrderID, s.OrderDate
FROM Sales.Customer AS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS s ON c.CustomerID = s.CustomerID
WHERE s.OrderDate = '2005/07/01';
```

--2

```
WITH orders AS (
SELECT SalesOrderID, CustomerID, OrderDate
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
WHERE OrderDate = '2005/07/01'
)
SELECT c.CustomerID, orders.SalesOrderID, orders.OrderDate
FROM Sales.Customer AS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders ON c.CustomerID = orders.CustomerID
ORDER BY orders.OrderDate DESC;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of `WHERE` clause in query 1. The `WHERE` clause filters the final result of the two tables being joined. You need to move the condition from `WHERE` clause into `ON`, *which filters the records (on table `Sales.SalesOrderHeader`) first before joining it to another table (`Sales.Customer`)*, [*you can also find it here.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706112/why-and-when-a-left-join-with-condition-in-where-clause-is-not-equivalent-to-the)

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, s.SalesOrderID, s.OrderDate
FROM   Sales.Customer AS c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS s 
           ON c.CustomerID = s.CustomerID  AND 
              s.OrderDate = '2005/07/01';
```

Comment: Thanks, the link was helpful also.

Answer (score 2):

You are killing the outer in the first by referencing a table in the where
Just move that condition into the join

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, s.SalesOrderID, s.OrderDate
 FROM Sales.Customer AS c
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS s 
   ON c.CustomerID = s.CustomerID
  AND s.OrderDate = '2005/07/01';
```