# MYSQL JOIN with IN clause

Tags: mysql

I have the following which returns specific posts from a table. As expected it gives 11 rows.

```
-- SQL gives 11 rows
select p.ID from wp_posts p where p.ID IN (2596, 2597, 2598, 2600, 2849, 2928, 2851, 2852, 3011, 2854, 2855);
```

I have a second table 'wp_raceresult' which records a person's race results. The person only has 7 results in this table. I want to get the details of all race results in this set of races for a specific runner, ie NULL for the each race where there is no result. The SQL i have atm only results the matching rows.

```
-- SQL only gives 7 rows
select p.ID,rr.leaguepoints from wp_posts p
join wp_raceresult rr on p.id=rr.race
where p.ID IN (2596, 2597, 2598, 2600, 2849, 2928, 2851, 2852, 3011, 2854, 2855)
and runner=7
```

I've tried using FULL OUTER, LEFT, RIGHT clauses and a UNION but without success. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have mentioned that you already tried `LEFT JOIN` and the result you got is not the one you expect, it is because you are querying for `runner = 7` in the final result. Move the statement on the `ON` clause and it will work.

```
SELECT  p.ID,
        rr.leaguepoints
FROM    wp_posts p
        LEFT JOIN wp_raceresult rr
            ON p.id = rr.race AND 
                rr.runner = 7                             -- <<=== move it here
WHERE p.ID IN (2596, 2597, 2598, 2600, 2849, 2928, 2851, 2852, 3011, 2854, 2855)
```

Additional info:

- [Why and when a LEFT JOIN with condition in WHERE clause is not equivalent to the same LEFT JOIN in ON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706112/why-and-when-a-left-join-with-condition-in-where-clause-is-not-equivalent-to-the)

Answer (score -1):

If you need all the record from one table, and the data matching in the reference table you can try with the `LEFT JOIN`

```
    select 
    p.ID,
    rr.leaguepoints 
    from wp_posts p
    LEFT join wp_raceresult rr on p.id=rr.race
    where p.ID IN (2596, 2597, 2598, 2600, 2849, 2928, 2851, 2852, 3011, 2854, 2855)
    and runner=7
```