# Getting Data from SQL Statement that is Null along with Data that isn't from a Query String

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

Here is my SQL Statement :

```
 SELECT machine, 
   fixedassets.[serial no], 
   [date] 
FROM   fixedassets 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN maintenancerecord 
                ON fixedassets.id = maintenancerecord.id 
WHERE  areaid = @AreaID 
   AND [record type] = 'Service History'
```

It's Currently being used by one of my tables in a GridView(`ASP.NET`) to show the Machines , Serial No of the Machines & the Date they was last serviced ( From Maintenance Record Where Record Type = Service History ) When I execute this through my Datasource attached to the GridView , it doesn't display the machines , for Example if the Area ID = **4** Then i know that at least **4** machines should appear even though they haven't yet received a Service History ( From a insert in a diff table but that's not the point it should still return them ) ... So my actual question is :  *Even If the machines have no Service History they should still be Returned in the table because that's what a `Left Outer Join` does right?*

Any more code that needs to be provided can / will do , just ask in the comments. 
Thanks you in advance!

Comment: Is this a right join condition `FixedAssets.ID = MaintenanceRecord.ID `?

Comment: If `AreaID = @AreaID AND [Record Type]='Service History'` is satisfied, you will get data. If not sure, please refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-and-left-outer-join-in-sql-server) question

Comment: Maybe I should re arrange the join , might help the query return of the results @shahkalpesh.

Comment: Who ever just edited my query , it looks terrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[record type]` should be check in the `ON` clause of the `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT machine, 
       fixedassets.[serial no], 
       [date] 
FROM   fixedassets 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN maintenancerecord 
          ON fixedassets.id = maintenancerecord.id 
             AND maintenancerecord.[record type] = 'Service History'
WHERE  areaid = @AreaID
```

Comment: [Read more on this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706112/why-and-when-a-left-join-with-condition-in-where-clause-is-not-equivalent-to-the)

Comment: You have guided my to my end goal , will mark as answer soon as possible.