# LEFT JOIN drops rows without filtering original table

Tags: mysql, left-join

The following query is confusing to me. It does *not* show all rows in the `products` table if I do `WHERE (inventory_to_pos.POSID IS NULL OR inventory_to_pos.POSID = ?)` and bind a `POSID` that may or may not exist in `inventory_to_pos`. When `LEFT JOIN`-ing a table, should I not get *all* rows from the original table, when I only filter on the original table and use `IS NULL` on any conditions for `LEFT JOIN`'ed tables?

```
SELECT products.ID,products.NAME,products.VOLUME,productcombinations.PRODUCTID,productcombinations.PART,inventory_to_pos.FULLCOUNT
FROM products
LEFT JOIN productcombinations ON products.ID = productcombinations.PARTOF
LEFT JOIN inventory_to_pos ON products.ID = inventory_to_pos.PRODUCT 
WHERE products.INVENTORY = 1
AND products.AVAILABLE = 1
AND products.ID > 0
AND (inventory_to_pos.POSID IS NULL OR inventory_to_pos.POSID = ?);
```

In the case where `inventory_to_pos.PRODUCT` and `inventory_to_pos.POSID` does not exist for the given product and POSID, I am given no rows. Why?

Comment: LEFT JOIN + WHERE = INNER JOIN (over same table), so put these additional condititions into LEFT JOIN statement.

Comment: How is that equal? I am not using WHERE on the column that is left joined? Can you show an example of what you mean?

Comment: you are trying `WHERE inventory_to_pos.POSID IS NULL`, right?

Comment: Yes, but OR have value X (bound)? I am not seeing the difference.

Comment: Please post an answer with a fix perhaps, so I can understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move all related `invetory_to_pos` clauses into LEFT JOIN, i.e.:

```
SELECT
    products.ID,
    products. NAME,
    products.VOLUME,
    productcombinations.PRODUCTID,
    productcombinations.PART,
    inventory_to_pos.FULLCOUNT
FROM
    products
LEFT JOIN productcombinations ON products.ID = productcombinations.PARTOF
LEFT JOIN inventory_to_pos ON products.ID = inventory_to_pos.PRODUCT AND (
    inventory_to_pos.POSID IS NULL
    OR inventory_to_pos.POSID = ?
)
WHERE
    products.INVENTORY = 1
AND products.AVAILABLE = 1
AND products.ID > 0
```

Comment: It worked. Wow. This is a huge gap in my general knowledge of how to filter joins.

Comment: Can you perhaps explain to me *why* we cannot filter in WHERE? I was always under the impression that this is where all filters should go.

Comment: In general because MySQL first filters the tables itself (it takes all WHERE statements) then do the join. So in your case the engine first will filter `inventory_to_pos` based on your WHERE clauses then will JOIN it, which is equal to INNER JOIN.

Comment: But.... based on my WHERE clause, I want rows that are either NULL OR have a specific value. I cannot comprehend how that is equal to an INNER JOIN, which requires rows in both tables? Totally stumped.

Comment: You mean that it filters inventory_to_pos based on filters made for products, which mean no rows qualify?

Comment: if you do `WHERE inventory_to_pos.POSID IS NULL` insead of LEFT JOIN, the engine will takes only corresponding records from `products` table that match on this condition together with `products.ID = inventory_to_pos.PRODUCT`. With LEFT JOIN, engine first takes ALL `products` rows then JOIN second table and "glue" his rows to original table. hope you understand the difference from these explanations :)

Comment: In other words INNER JOIN = (table1+table2) then filter, LEFT JOIN = (table1 with filter) + (table2 with filter)

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752455/left-join-with-where-clause, and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706112/why-and-when-a-left-join-with-condition-in-where-clause-is-not-equivalent-to-the

Comment: No problem! If my answer solves your problem just mark/check it in order to close the topic.

Comment: Yeah I was going to, just had to wait for the timer :)