# MYSQL - using AND in JOIN versus WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

If I have this query:

```
select * from tableA
left outer join tableB on tableA.id=tableB.id
AND tableB.foo = 1
where tableA.owner=10
```

I get 29 results, but if I move that AND into the WHERE clause like:

```
select * from tableA
left outer join tableB on tableA.id=tableB.id
where tableA.owner=10
AND tableB.foo = 1
```

I then get only 17 results.

I've looked all around and cannot find a definitive guide as to how using the AND differs when you use it in the JOIN versus the WHERE clause.  Can anyone explain this to me?

Also, if I do something like `AND tableB.foo = NULL` in the JOIN all of my tableB.foo fields are NULL in the query results, even if they are not null in the table.  Does having the AND in the JOIN clause change that field in the FROM selection before being filtered by the WHERE clause?

Comment: you can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15706298/7416478

Answer (score 1):

All of the criteria for the table you are outer-joining to should be in the `JOIN` clause (like your first query). Putting it in the `WHERE` clause (like your second query) implicitly converts the `OUTER JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`.

As for your question about `AND tableB.foo = NULL` that is not proper MySQL syntax. NULLs require [special treatment](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html), using operators like `IS NULL`. You should use `AND tableB.foo IS NULL` instead.

Answer (score 1):

An outer join joins just the same as an inner join. With the addition that when there is no match for a record, a dummy record with all columns set to null gets joined (so you still get the row from the first table in your results).

In your first query you are looking for matches in tableB with the same ID and foo = 1. For records in tableA with no such match you still get a result row (with all tableA fields null).

In the second query you are looking for matches in tableB with the same ID. For records in tableA with no such match you still get a result row (with all tableA fields null). Then in your where clause you only keep rows with foo = 1. This dismisses all outer-joined records (because their foo is null) and you are where you would have been with a plain inner join.

So always put all criteria on an outer-joined table in the ON clause. (There is one exception though; an anti join, but you can learn that pattern another time.)