# Why isn't my condition in the ON clause working?

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I have two tables, for which I want to left join only rows in **main_sys** where curr_flag = 1 to **integrated_sys**. These queries are returning different rows, and I can't figure out why.

**SEE REXTESTER FOR QUERY RESULTS: http://rextester.com/YYR54058**

```
QUERY 1 - curr_flag filter is in WHERE clause
select 
    * 
from 
    main_sys m
    left join integrated_sys i  on (m.master_id_sysa = i.master_id_sysa 
                                    or m.master_id_sysb = i.master_id_sysb)
where
    m.curr_flag = 1


QUERY 2 - curr_flag filter is in ON clause
select 
    * 
from 
    main_sys m
    left join integrated_sys i  on (   (
                                       m.master_id_sysa = i.master_id_sysa 
                                       or m.master_id_sysb = i.master_id_sysb
                                       ) 
                                   and m.curr_flag = 1
                                   )
```

Table A: **main_sys** contains historical records for locations.

```
| hist_id | master_id_sysA | master_id_sysB | loc_desc    | curr_flag | eff_start_dt | eff_end_dt |
|---------|----------------|----------------|-------------|-----------|--------------|------------|
| 14009   | 1234           | 1234           | Detroit, MI | 1         | 7/2/2017     | 1/1/9999   |
| 14010   | 1234           | 1234           | Detroit, MI | 0         | 1/6/2017     | 7/1/2017   |
| 14011   | 1234           | 1234           | Detroit, MI | 0         | 9/2/2016     | 1/5/2017   |
| 14012   | 1234           | 1234           | Detroit, MI | 0         | 7/23/2016    | 9/1/2016   |
| 14013   | 1234           | 1234           | Detroit, MI | 0         | 5/31/2015    | 7/22/2016  |
| 90088   | 6655           | 6655           | Dover, DE   | 1         | 6/2/2015     | 6/21/2015  |
| 90087   | 6655           | 6655           | Dover, DE   | 0         | 6/1/2015     | 6/1/2015   |
| 90086   | 6655           | 6655           | Dover, DE   | 0         | 5/31/2015    | 5/31/2015  |
| 14413   | 8877           | NULL           | NULL        | 1         | 9/2/2017     | 12/31/9999 |
| 14412   | 8877           | 877            | Austin, TX  | 0         | 8/3/2017     | 9/1/2017   |
| 14411   | 8877           | NULL           | NULL        | 0         | 6/19/2017    | 8/2/2017   |
| 14410   | 8877           | 877            | NULL        | 0         | 2/18/2017    | 6/18/2017  |
| 14409   | 8877           | 877            | Austin, TX  | 0         | 2/16/2017    | 2/17/2017  |
| 14145   | 9595           | 9595           | Boston, MA  | 1         | 9/9/2006     | 10/10/2014 |
| 39014   | 9987           | 9987           | Atlanta, GA | 1         | 6/5/2017     | 1/1/9999   |
| 39013   | 9987           | 9987           | Atlanta, GA | 0         | 11/1/2016    | 6/4/2017   |
| 39012   | 9987           | 9987           | Atlanta, GA | 0         | 9/23/2016    | 10/31/2016 |
| 39011   | 9987           | 9987           | Atlanta, GA | 0         | 7/6/2016     | 9/22/2016  |
| 39010   | 9987           | 9987           | Atlanta, GA | 0         | 1/6/2016     | 7/5/2016   |
```

Table B - **integrated_sys** table has the current record of each location.

```
| loc_name       | master_id_sysA | master_id_sysB |
|----------------|----------------|----------------|
| Detroit, MI    | 1234           | 1234           |
| Atlanta, GA    | 9987           | 9987           |
| Dover, DE      | 6655           | 6655           |
| Boston, MA     | NULL           | 9595           |
| Tempe, AZ      | NULL           | 55             |
| Seattle, OR    | NULL           | 95             |
| Des Moines, IO | NULL           | 1478           |
| Bismarck, SD   | NULL           | 1515           |
```

**This question explains the situation, but I still don't know why the ON clause query is returning rows where curr_flag is 0:** [Why and when a LEFT JOIN with condition in WHERE clause is not equivalent to the same LEFT JOIN in ON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706112/why-and-when-a-left-join-with-condition-in-where-clause-is-not-equivalent-to-the)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `m.curr_flag = 1` is part of a `LEFT JOIN` condition then it is not used to select rows from the left table, only from the right table. `LEFT JOIN` simply keep all input rows from the left table despite any condition behind `ON`. Therefore, if you need to filter data of the left table then you should write such condition behind `WHERE` clause (your first query).

Answer (score 1):

Because they are logically different.

Query 1 - Select all record from left table where curr_flag = 1 , keep all the records from the right table when the `ON()` clause is true -> `m.master_id_sysa = i.master_id_sysa or m.master_id_sysb = i.master_id_sysb`

Query 2 - Select all record from left table , keep all the records from the right table when the `ON()` clause is true -> `(m.master_id_sysa = i.master_id_sysa or m.master_id_sysb = i.master_id_sysb) AND m.curr_flag = 1`

**EDIT:** For clarification - the `ON()` clause of a left join does not filter records from the `LEFT` table, it filters only the `RIGHT` table.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean for Qry 2 - "keep all the records from the right table when the ON() clause is true"? Shouldn't only the rows where curr_flag = 1 be returned, or does the ON() clause not limit result sets?