# Symfony QueryBuilder - filter collection in query

Tags: database, symfony, join, query-builder

I have a query like this:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('supervision')
        ->join('supervision.supervisionEvents', 'supervisionEvents')
        ->andWhere('supervisionEvents.episode = :episode')
        ->setParameter('episode', $episode)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
        ;
```

I want to get all supervisions but the supervisionEvents I want to filter. 
In result I only want to have SupervisionEvents with episode = :episode.

I used join, leftJoin and innerJoin. Nothing works like desired.

I tried to have a condition on the join:

```
 ->innerJoin('s.supervisionEvents', 'supervisionEvent', 'WITH', 'supervisionEvent.episode = :episode')
```

But thats also not working!

Comment: This is the expected behaviour, if you only want to have some SupervisionEvents you need to filter them with php or change the query to search for SupervisionEvents only.

Comment: the expected behavior is, that u can not have a join with a condition?

Comment: You can have a join with a condition, but this will only change the found supervision entities. Your query (with innerjoin) means something like 'get all supervision entities where at least one event has episode = :episode'. With doctrine you don't have to think like normal sql but about objects, doctrine will always load all related entities and you can not change that.

Answer (score -1):

You are actually pretty close. You want to **filter only on the join**, so use a left join with condition to the **join clause**:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('supervision')
    ->addSelect('supervisionEvents')
    ->leftJoin('supervision.supervisionEvents', 'supervisionEvents', Join::WITH, 'supervisionEvents.episode = :episode')
    ->setParameter('episode', $episode)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
    ;
```

It is needed also to **select the joined relation**, so that it is hydrated on the result.

References

- [doctrine left join with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55599015/4448410)
- [Why and when a LEFT JOIN with condition in WHERE clause is not equivalent to the same LEFT JOIN in ON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706112/why-and-when-a-left-join-with-condition-in-where-clause-is-not-equivalent-to-the)